# Android - Activity orientation stuck after Camera Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, orientation

In our application, the user presses a button which opens the Android default camera activity.

Snippet on how we start the camera activity:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, FILE_PROVIDER, image);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

The problem is if the Activity is in portrait mode, everything works fine, camera is in portrait mode, image gets saved in the correct orientation, etc.

In landscape mode though, the camera starts and after returning the activity is stuck in portrait mode and does not change by tilting the phone anymore.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

EDIT: code of onActivityResult(...)

EDIT2: resolved custom methods

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        //returns Filehandler to image
        File objektImage = getImageForObjekt(loadedObjekt);

        correctImageRotation(objektImage);

        //ImageView
        this.imgObjekt.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(objektImage.getAbsolutePath()));
    }
}
```

This method corrects the image rotation - cameras on Samsung phones stored them in the wrong orientation which is corrected here:

```
public boolean correctImageRotation(File img) {
    ExifInterface ei;
    try {
        ei = new ExifInterface(img.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    Log.d(this._LOGKEY, getLogPraefix()+" Store the new Objekt image to: " + img.getName());

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath());

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            bm = rotateImage(bm, 90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            bm = rotateImage(bm, 180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            bm = rotateImage(bm, 270);
            break;
    }

    bm = ImageHelper.squarify(bm);
    bm = ImageHelper.compress(bm, ImageHelper.Size.large);

    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(img);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(_LOGKEY, getLogPraefix()+": file not found.");
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(_LOGKEY, getLogPraefix()+": IO problem.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This method cuts the image s.t. it is square-shaped afterwards:

```
public static Bitmap squarify(Bitmap srcBmp) {
    Bitmap dstBmp;

    if (srcBmp.getWidth() >= srcBmp.getHeight()){

        dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                srcBmp,
                srcBmp.getWidth()/2 - srcBmp.getHeight()/2,
                0,
                srcBmp.getHeight(),
                srcBmp.getHeight()
        );

    }else{

        dstBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                srcBmp,
                0,
                srcBmp.getHeight()/2 - srcBmp.getWidth()/2,
                srcBmp.getWidth(),
                srcBmp.getWidth()
        );
    }

    return dstBmp;
}
```

And finally this method compresses the image in one of three possible sizes:

```
public static Bitmap compress(Bitmap srcBmp, Size size) {
    int side;

    switch (size) {
        default:
        case small:
            side = 200;
            break;
        case medium:
            side = 400;
            break;
        case large:
            side = 800;
            break;
    }

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBmp, side, side, true);
}
```

Comment: So, if i understand, in the second situatuon you launch the camera from the activity in landscape, camera starts in landscape, and you return to your activity and its in portrait?

Comment: Exactly, the camera itself is in landscape (which is seen by the orientation of the buttons) but as soon as the old activity is launched again it is stuck in portrait.

Comment: But your activity before launching the camera is in landscape? Does your app work in landscape?

Comment: The activity has a seperate layout for landscape and loads it correctly as well on orientation switch.

Comment: Maybe share the code from `onActivityResult()` ? Its a weird behaviour that your activity is stuck.

Comment: I edited the question above. It seems that the bug does not come up at our tablet though. The phone is a Huawei P20 Pro

Comment: I think you should share more code. What does this do `correctImageRotation(objektImage);`

Comment: I tried to resolve all methods i introduced by myself above.

Comment: The problem disappeared. I was working on other issues and the bug disappeared without any changes whatsoever.

Comment: That is more than weird. Maybe different device? Maybe updated Android version? Maybe updated dependencies in Gradle? etc